# Ito's Lemma for this problem

Tags: brownian-motion, itos-lemma

I'm attempting to prove a lemma from a paper, in the context of optimal contracts.

$r,\rho,\gamma,\alpha,\sigma$ are all known constants.

$dR_t = (\alpha + r)dt + \sigma dZ_t$ where $Z_t$ is a standard Brownian motion.

*Lemma 1*

Given an incentive compatible contract, the agent's consumption must satisfy
$$\frac{dc_t}{c_t} = \left( \frac{r - \rho}{\gamma} + \frac{1+\gamma}{2} 
 (\sigma^c_t)^2
 \right) dt +
 \sigma^c_t \frac{1}{\sigma} \left( dR_t - (\alpha + r) dt \right)
 + dL_t$$
for some stochastic process $\sigma^c$ and a weakly increasing stochastic process $L$.

*Proof*

The authors provide the following steps:

1. $e^{-(\rho - r)t}c_t^{\gamma}$ is a supermartingale, thus we can express it as 
   $$ e^{-(\rho - r)t}c_t^{\gamma} = M_t - A_t$$
   where $M_t$ is a martingale and $A_t$ is a weakly increasing process.
2. Applying the martingale representation theorem to $M_t$, there exists a stochastic process $\sigma^M_t$ such that 
   $$M_t = \int_0^{t} \sigma^M_t dZ_t$$ where $Z_t$ is a standard Brownian motion.
3. They then apply Ito's Lemma to get the first equation by setting $\sigma^M_t = -\gamma \sigma^c_t e^{-(\rho - r)t}c_t^{\gamma}$.

I'm struggling at step 3, as I am not sure how the Ito differential looks like for $M_t$.

This is what I've done:
$$- (\rho - r) e^{-(\rho - r) t}c_t^{-\gamma} dt - \gamma e^{-(\rho - r)t} 
 c_t^{\gamma - 1} dc_t = dM_t - dA_t $$
    Substituting in $dM_t$ and dividing by $K = e^{-(\rho - r) t} 
 c_t^{-\gamma}$,

$$(r - \rho) dt - \gamma \frac{dc_t}{c_t} = K^{-1} \sigma^M_t dZ_t - K^{-1} 
  dA_t$$
    Define $\sigma^c_t = (-\gamma K)^{-1} \sigma^M_t$ and $dL_t = (\gamma 
 K)^{-1} dA_t $, and thus
$$
 \frac{dc_t}{c_t} = \frac{r - \rho}{\gamma} dt + \sigma^c_t dZ_t + dL_t
$$
    Plug in $dZ_t = \frac{1}{\sigma} \left( dR_t - (r + \alpha) dt \right)$ 
    (a previous result) and the 
    result follows.

Where does the $\frac{1+\gamma}{2} (\sigma^c_t)^2$ term come from?

Comment: Which paper and which result?

Comment: @Sanjay Di Tella and Sannikov, Optimal Asset Management Contracts with Hidden
Savings, Lemma 2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You missed the quadratic term, specifically, rather than
\begin{align*}
- (\rho - r) e^{-(\rho - r) t}c_t^{-\gamma} dt - \gamma e^{-(\rho - r)t} 
 c_t^{-\gamma - 1} dc_t &= dM_t - dA_t, 
\end{align*}
we have
\begin{align*}
& - (\rho - r) e^{-(\rho - r) t}c_t^{-\gamma} dt - \gamma e^{-(\rho - r)t} 
 c_t^{-\gamma - 1} dc_t + \frac{1}{2} \gamma (\gamma+1)e^{-(\rho - r)t} 
 c_t^{-\gamma - 2} d\langle c, c\rangle_t \\
&=\ dM_t - dA_t.
\end{align*}
That is,
\begin{align*}
\frac{dc_t}{c_t} = \frac{r - \rho}{\gamma} dt +\frac{1}{2}(\gamma+1)c_t^{-2}d\langle c, c\rangle_t + \sigma^c_t dZ_t + dL_t.
\end{align*}
Moreover, 
\begin{align*}
c_t^{-2}d\langle c, c\rangle_t = \big(\sigma_t^c\big)^2 dt.
\end{align*}
Therefore, 
\begin{align*}
\frac{dc_t}{c_t} = \frac{r - \rho}{\gamma} dt +\frac{1}{2}(\gamma+1)\big(\sigma_t^c\big)^2 dt + \sigma^c_t dZ_t + dL_t.
\end{align*}

Comment: Thank you very much! In the case where $c$ is a scalar, $d<c,c>_t$ is just $(dc)^2$?

Comment: Generally, yes; it is a notation that is used in most rigor math books.